# force inputfield doesn't display fields anymore , can't figure out the reason?

Tags: issue, forceinputfield

I'm new to lightning code and this code worked for me on Friday but after the winter'19 releases it doesn't work anymore nothing shows up, Can you please help me with this I'm not sure if the Event object still supported or not ??

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
 <aura:attribute name="event" type="Event" 
                default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Event' }"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

Objet

```
    <div><p>Contact</p>
        <force:inputField value="{!v.event.WhoId}" />
       </div>
    <div><p>Location</p>
        <force:inputField value="{!v.event.Location}" />
       </div>
    <div><p>Compte</p>
        <force:inputField value="{!v.event.WhatId}" />
       </div>
</lightning:card>
```

Comment: do you notice any errors in your console since it stoped working?

Comment: No anything !!!!

Comment: for more information I added this component in an account page in order to create event from this account but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: I can confirm that this is not related to Winter '19 as I verified it in a Winter '19 sandbox and works fine. Could be specific to that sandbox, or if something has changed in the code itself. If it still does not work, I will recommend to reach out to Salesforce support.

Comment: I found the issue the <lightning:card> when I remove it it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **`<lightning:card>`** is deprecated and now it's required to add title attribute to this lightning tag so it should be written this way **`<lightning:card title="title of the card">`**